# How do you activate an onTouchEvent() motion within a particular aspect of your view?

Tags: android, layout

For example, i have a scrollView and a LinearLayout within one of my XML files. The LinearLayout is a small bar at the bottom of the screen used as navigation (70dp high).

I want to make it so that if a user swipes up/down within this LinearLayout it will display another LinearLayout just beneath it. Sort of like an expanded menu.

I have the extended layout created and placed and the animations are working. But i can't get it to swipe up/down within the LinearLayout.

How do i do this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Code Example

This is an example of the XML

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/llSM"
    />
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/llSM"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llNav"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bWebsite"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/nhome"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bShop"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/nhome"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bFacebook"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/nfacebook"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bHome"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nhome"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bContact"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ncontactus"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bHome"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bBooking"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/onlinebooking"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bContact"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the Main example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_external);

    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llNav);
    ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    animUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_up);
    animDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_down);

    NavBar(); //This just loads the buttons and their intents
    Links(); //This is for the second linear layout loading social media
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    myWebView.loadUrl("url");


    ll2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSM);

    ll2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                startY = event.getY();
                //hello you just touched me!!!
            } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                float endY = event.getY();
                if ((endY < startY) && (a==0)) {
                    ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ll.startAnimation(animUp);
                    a = a+1;
                }
                else {
                    if ((endY > startY) && (a>=1)){
                        ll.startAnimation(animDown);
                        ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        a = 0;
                    }
                }
            }


            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

The WebView scrolls within it so it will not work in there. I want to be able to swipe on the linearlayout labelled "llSM" to bring up the "llNav" bar just beneath it and push everything up. I also need to click the buttons on the "llSM" bar to navigate between different web views.

Answer (score 0):

The `LinearLayout` you are talking about is a `View` + Group , so call `View.OnTouchListener` on it

```
thatParticularLinearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

        //hello you just touched me!!! 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

**EDIT 1**

your code is great sir, but there's something in android called `onInterceptTouchEvent()` what is does is perfect for your case like i said linearLayout -(**llSM** and **llNav**) is a `ViewGroup` so you can call `onInterceptTouchEvent()` for it to intercept all touch events before his children even sees it.. maintain your touch event code..

okay so [read more](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html) here, they even have code samples to support you.. [and more](http://tiku.io/questions/1766746/using-onintercepttouchevent) , [and more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661884/using-onintercepttouchevent) ..

**EDIT 2**
okay, from what you want try extending `ViewFlipper` i love it, its great. or `ViewAnimator` they will make your work easy.. lets see,

```
   public class Noodles extends ViewFlipper { // for your situation i will say extend this.. i am not saying this is
// the only way but that's the best and easiest i can think of..
// this viewgroup will be in a viewgroup maybe linear layout.. but those child linearlayout
// declare them like in different layouts okay..

Context context;// context to use
boolean intercept; // i dont know if i will use this but to indicate if it will intercept
View[] children;
float inx,iny = (float) 0.000; // this is the touched position that will be captured in on down in your touch
// i am not a OMG mathmatician but if you equate it to 0, its allways going to fail.. so the number of infinity
// depends on you.d thats just btw, so try it and see maybe i might be wrong

public Noodles(Context context,View[] children/* or LinearLayout[] children*/) { // construtor.. with the child layouts 
    super(context);     
    this.context = context;
    this.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); // setting params..
    this.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, someSickAnimationThatwILLSlidInFromTop)); // the animation should follow the pattern like this "R.anim.abc_slide_in_top" this is a default in animation
     /// but the spelling might differ
    this.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, someSickAnimationThatwILLSlidOutFromTop));
    this.children = children;
    for(int i=0;i<children.length;i++){
        this.addView(children[i]);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    // here you can use math catch the movement, something like 0,0 [x,y];
    // get the point loaction at with it was touched
    // when y increases it is coming down, when it decresse it is going up - all in respect to the intial
    // point.. you can intercept when y increase by a set of marging lets say like 20..or 10, because
    // eventually x will increase as is it is not straight line..but i can not rilly say, because i am conjuring from how it worksk,maybe im right maybe i am not   
    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        Log.v("Noodles", "triggered");
        intercept = false;
    }
    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        Log.v("Noodles", "noodles intercept fired"); 
        intercept = true;

        return true;
    }
    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        if(intercept)  // yes i do 
            return true;
    }
    Log.v("Noodles", "noodles intercept ignored");
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    // i think you can do the calculation 
    // to know if its going up or down respectively
    // use this.showNext(); for showing the next item from bottom to top the this.showPrevious vice versa
    Log.v("Noodles", "noodles touch fired");
    //i am trying the calculation, use and see if it works
    float inx,iny = 0;
    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        Log.v("touchy", "triggered");
        iny = ev.getY();
        inx = ev.getX();
        Log.v("touchy", "x : " +String.valueOf(inx));
        Log.v("touchy", "y : " +String.valueOf(iny));
    }

    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        int retval = Float.compare(iny, ev.getY());

        if(retval > 0){
            //noodles i am goin up 
            // this flips the current view out with upward movement animation you declared the in
            Log.v("touchy", "i am going up"); 
        }else if(retval < 0){
            // noodles i am goin down
            // this flips the current view out with downward movement
            Log.v("touchy", "i am going down");
        }
        // you can put your animations in their respective statements and rememba to call this.showNext(); in the upward movement and this.ShowPrevious(); the other
        iny = ev.getY();
        Log.v("touchy", "y : " +String.valueOf(iny));
        return true;
    }

    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        // finger is up..
        //return true; //this goes agains the logic but i am thinking to prevent the return false argument, depends on how
        // you playing.. 
    }


}
```

}

Comming to your MainActivity instatiate this `Noodles` here

```
// in your actvity instatiate it
Noodles n = new Noodles(this,View1,View2); 
// then add it to your parent view or your layout that is to be your navigation
```

**Please if you copy and paste this, you might see some unusual error, just correct them ok, because they are pretty chubby i thinking** *when i get to my laptop i will correct them for future use*

Let me know if it helps..

Comment: I just tried to implement this, however it didn't work :(

Could it be because there are image buttons within the linearlayout? I will edit my post above with code.

Comment: Code added. I've probably done everything wrong as i'm new to Android. Thanks for your help!

Comment: oh okay, so both llsm and llnav will both receive this swipe right? okay hold up@Noodelz

Comment: i have editted it, and included links that have codes to help your case if you still find it tedious then when im pretty free, i will do codes @Noodelz , sorry for the delay SIr, things arising

Comment: Thanks so much! I will give this a shot and see how I go :) If i can't get it working then i might be back haha.

Comment: If you're bored and feel like throwing up an example then it would be greatly appreciated :P I've read over the examples linked and tried to implement then, but failed a few different ways. Now i'm stuck scratching my head again ha.

Comment: i have edited to add some deep code Sir @Noodelz but the only problem is i spelt yur name with a "s" instead of "z". hope it helps

Comment: After trying to implement this, i gave up and changed the whole design ha. Now i'm going with a Navigation Drawer instead and just swiping from the left. Thanks for your help though! It was greatly appreciated, but i just couldn't figure it out :/